# Speed Up Clear Contents

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Think my issue is trying to clear the 50,000 rows in multiple worksheets at the same time. Is there another way to do this? Possibly use a For loop in the range to speed up the process or a multirange array?

```
  Sub VBA_Clear_Contents_Range()
    Dim Dashboard_1, Dashboard_2, Dashboard_3, Data_1, Data_2, Data_3, Detail_1, Detail_2, 
    Detail_3 As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set Dashboard_1 = Sheets("Dashboard_1")
    Set Dashboard_2 = Sheets("Dashboard_2")
    Set Dashboard_3 = Sheets("Dashboard_3")
    Set Data_1 = Sheets("Data_1")
    Set Data_2 = Sheets("Data_2")
    Set Data_3 = Sheets("Data_3")
    Set Detail_1 = Sheets("Detail_1")
    Set Detail_2 = Sheets("Detail_2")
    Set Detail_3 = Sheets("Detail_3")
           
    Dashboard_1.Range("AB11:AB15,AB21:AB25,AB28:AB32,AB38:AB42,L7:P7").ClearContents                
    Dashboard_2.Range("AB11:AB15,AB21:AB25,AB28:AB32,AB38:AB42,L7:P7").ClearContents
    Dashboard_3.Range("AB11:AB15,AB21:AB25,AB28:AB32,AB38:AB42,L7:P7").ClearContents
    
    Data_1.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    Data_2.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    Data_3.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    
    Detail_1.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    Detail_2.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    Detail_3.Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is something else going on with your workbook that's slowing things down.  I've created a test workbook, and placed arbitarily large strings in the range `A2:AG50000` on the `Data_*` an `Details_*` sheets.  Running your code takes less than 2 seconds for me. I suggest you 1) try to verify my results (create a new workbook with arbitary data similar to your real data, and run your code on it).  If you achieve a fast run time, then consider what else is in your workbook that might slow things down.

Comment: ^^^ 2) verify it's the 50000 row clear that is the slow part (comment out the different section of code and run to measure the time taken)

Comment: ^^^ 3) update this post the results of the above, and with a description of the data in the Data and Details sheets

Comment: Yes, your right. I created another WB and it ran just fine and very fast. There must be something else going on in my WB. I did comment out the `A2:AG50000` and it ran just fine and quick. I'll investigate more. Thanks for the troubleshooting ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer helps, along with that, you should look at combining your ranges, like this ...

`Dashboard_1.Range("AB11:AB15,AB21:AB25,AB28:AB32,AB38:AB42,L7:P7").ClearContents`

... it may not have a huge impact on performance but it will cut down the code and the amount of calls being made to each worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FillAcrossSheets` method:

```
Sub VBA_Clear_Contents_Range()
    Dim Dsb As Sheets, Dta As Sheets
    Dim r As Variant

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set Dsb = Sheets(Array("Dashboard_1", "Dashboard_2", "Dashboard_3"))
    Set Dta = Sheets(Array("Data_1", "Data_2", "Data_3", _
                           "Detail_1", "Detail_2", "Detail_3"))

    For Each r In Array("AB11:AB15", "AB21:AB25", "AB38:AB42", "L7:P7")
        ' Dsb(1).Range(r).ClearContents
        Dsb(1).Range(r).Value = vbNullString
        Dsb.FillAcrossSheets Dsb(1).Range(r)
    Next r

    ' Dta(1).Range("A2:AG50000").ClearContents
    Dta(1).Range("A2:AG50000").Value = vbNullString 
    Dta.FillAcrossSheets Dta(1).Range("A2:AG50000")

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked but took about the same amount of time to finish. Around 1:42min. I like how it is less lines of code but would be nice to save a little bit more runtime.

Comment: Try another version. Instead of `ClearContents` you can assign `NullString`.